# Is there any way to determine a users DNS servers from a web page?

Tags: dns, web, detection

I am curious how I could detect a users DNS servers from my website. Is there any way to know? Any possible way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. By the time the user initiates the request to your server, the DNS lookup is already finished (or they wouldn't know the address of your server).

I suppose it's theoretically possible to abuse Javascript or other content in order to breach the security of the user's machine and try to fetch its configuration data, but I doubt you will get much help with that here.